# Как сделать период дат для if else php?

Tags: php

есть к прмеру период 20 декабря - 11 января

Я могу получить текующую датту следующим образом

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
   $simpleDate = date('Y-m-d');
   echo $simpleDate;
```

И мне надо задать условия что если текущая дата совпадает с периодом 20 декабря 11 января, выполнить условия. Вопрос, как можно сделать что бы без не писать все дни, а только период дабы условия выполнялось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
$now = new DateTime('2023-01-01');
if(checkInterval($now)) {
    echo 'Here';
}


function checkInterval($date) {
    $month =  $date->format('m');
    $day = $date->format('d');
    
    if ($month == 12 && $day >= 20) {
       return true;
    } else if ($month == 1 && $day <= 11) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php)

Comment: А что делать с годом? 25 декабря 2019 года попадает под условия вопроса, но не удовлетворяет условиям в вашем коде.

Comment: Согласен, поправил